# jQuery UI - Draggable + Droppable entire list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm trying to create a Draggable + Droppable list, and so far i've managed to make it work with single items of the list.

But i want to be able to drag and drop an entire list. Is that possible?

What i have is a nested accordian with a few lists and a droppable div to receive the items:

```
<div>
<div id="faqs-container" style="float: left; width: 250px"  class="accordian">
<h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>
<div class="accordian">
    <h3><a class=href="#">A</a></h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>list1</li>
                <li>list2</li>
                <li>list3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="#">B</a></h3>
        <div>    
            <ul>
                <li>list4</li>
                <li>list5</li>
                <li>list6</li>
            </ul>
       </div>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 200px">
                <div class="grupoFinal">
                    <div class="ui-widget-content">
                        <ol>
                            <li class="placeholder">Drop here!</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

And with jquery i make it work:

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,


});
$("div.accordian li").draggable({
    //appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});
$(".grupoFinal ol").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
    $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Here i have [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pboga/XD3d9/).

So, what i want do do is to drag an entire list, for example, list A, and drop all the item inside on the droppable div. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have basically what you are looking for, you might need to fiddle with it. My changes are here http://jsfiddle.net/XD3d9/12/

First I gave the h3 a class, the name was just random.

```
<h3 class="boots"><a  href="#">A</a></h3>
```

Then I needed to make it draggable, simple.

```
$('.boots').draggable({
   helper: 'clone'
});
```

Then I needed to figure out which element was being dragged. When you drag the h3 it takes every thing from that list and puts it on one line into the new list. If you wanted it broken apart I left that part to you to figure out, you should be able to ;).

```
$(".grupoFinal ol").droppable({
 drop: function (event, ui) {
  $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
    if (ui.draggable.prop('tagName') === 'LI') {
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    }
    if (ui.draggable.prop('tagName') === 'H3') {
        $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.next('div').text()).appendTo(this);
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot. Now i'm trying to display each item, as you said to break apart, but not having much luck with that. Inside of the second if, i iterate through the contents of the div with this: `ui.draggable.next('div').contents().children().each`. And, inside the function i try to append it `$("<li></li>").text($(this).contents().text()).appendTo(this);`
Check the updated demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/pboga/XD3d9/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/pboga/XD3d9/14/)

Comment: fixed it! It has to do with the 'this' keyword. It refers to the current function, so you were appending to the list you dragged it from. http://jsfiddle.net/clurect/XD3d9/15/

Comment: yeah, i've managed to make it work just after i've post the comment. Thanks a lot @clurect!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing `li` you can use `ul`

```
$("div.accordian ul").draggable({
    //appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone"
});
$(".grupoFinal ol").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
    $("<ul></ul>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    //---  get the next element
    $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.next('div').text()).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

This makes the whole list as draggable.

Comment: hum... thanks, but this doesn't really work. With your solution, i'm able to drag all the items, but what i want is to still be able to drag items individually and add a functionality where i can drag the entire list, by selecting it's name. In the demo i gave, i want to drag the <h3><a href="#">B</a></h3> and drop all the list items nested inside of it.